# Wagtail Tinymce - ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'wagtail.wagtailadmin'

Tags: python, django, tinymce, wagtail

I'm trying to install the package "wagtailtinymce" already downloaded it, however, the repository tutorial is completely bad. I do not know if it's because of some update or something. I'm using the latest version of wagtail and I already have a project created (obvious).

The error is in every import the package tries to make, and since I'm starting in Django and Wagtail, I do not know what to do. I have not been able to migrate the application yet because of this error.

```
File "/mnt/sda3/Development/Projetos/blog-wagtail/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/wagtailtinymce/wagtail_hooks.py", line 37, in <module>
    from wagtail.wagtailadmin.templatetags.wagtailadmin_tags import hook_output
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'wagtail.wagtailadmin'

File "/mnt/sda3/Development/Projetos/blog-wagtail/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/wagtailtinymce/wagtail_hooks.py", line 29, in <module>
    from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django.core.urlresolvers'
```

The import of django passed when I changed to "from django.urls import reverse" but the rest I do not know what to do, and I believe it will continue to give error every import

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the documentation, https://github.com/isotoma/wagtailtinymce#wagtail-tinymce , this module is compatible with Wagtail 1.5 and currently we are in the 2.3 version.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned, the pip package for `wagtailtinymce` is not up to date for latest versions of `wagtail`.

However, the github repo of the package has a branch named `wagtail40` which is compatible with the latest version.

To install, instead of using `pip install wagtailtinymce`, use `pip install git+https://github.com/isotoma/wagtailtinymce.git@wagtail40` and following other steps mentioned in the docs should work.

Tested in `Django==4.1.2` and `wagtail==4.0.4`