# Is there a Rich text Editor for Wagtail that allows users to select font size?

Tags: tinymce, wagtail

I am using wagtail and my user wishes to be able to change font sizes in the Rich text editor. I have attempted to use [TinyMCE](https://pypi.org/project/wagtailtinymce/) but the install is problematic (see this [question and non-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52996511/wagtail-tinymce-modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-wagtail-wagtailadmin))

Is there an alternative that would provide the functionality that I am looking for?

Answer (score 3):

You'd probably consider this a non-answer too, but if a rich text editor with that feature did exist, it would be [breaking the design principles of Wagtail](https://docs.wagtail.io/en/stable/getting_started/the_zen_of_wagtail.html#a-cms-should-get-information-out-of-an-editor-s-head-and-into-a-database-as-efficiently-and-directly-as-possible). Wagtail is a system for capturing and presenting *information*, not a web design package, and mixing the two is liable to lead to all kinds of problems down the line (inconsistent styling between pages, difficulty redesigning or migrating the site in future, accessibility for screen-reader users).

The correct alternative is to find out what information your client wishes to communicate with different font sizes, and then make sure you're modelling that information in your page models. For example, if they want to include [pull-quotes](http://www.magazinedesigning.com/pull-quotes/) in their text, you can model the page content as a [StreamField](https://docs.wagtail.io/en/stable/topics/streamfield.html) with a pull-quote block type (with its own text style defined by you in HTML/CSS). If they don't have any specific informational purpose in mind, and just want to play around with fonts, then gently advise them that that's your job, not theirs...

Comment: No I think this is constructive (if not was I was hoping for). I've tried to explain to them some basic principles of typography, but they want what they want. Clients eh?

Comment: While I sympathize with that zen, having created two cms myself over the years, it's still so 2010'ish :-). Today people want page builders, they want to create page content with arbitrary layout cols and rows, and don't accept restriction by our zen philosophies. And they are right.

Comment: @Bachi Wanting something doesn't automatically make it right.

Comment: @gasman depends on the perspective. After all, we build cms' for our clients, not for ourselves (mostly). And, client is king :).

Btw I've built a row/column layout based site in Wagtail now using streamfields and column blocks. Works nicely, but the UI of course is complex due to the nesting levels. Still trying to figure how to make it easier for the editors.